# GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/res/locales/es-419/allstrings.json net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: http-status-code-404, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm using Autodesk Forge APIs for developing a web application and everything is working fine, but a new message has appeared in the browser console while developing.

GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/res/locales/es-419/allstrings.json net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

[browser console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC22l.png)

[browser console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwr86.png)

[browser console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWXJy.png)

This is how I include Forge in my project:

src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"

I've looked up the Changelog of Autodesk Forge and I've found a new change with the latest version.

7.68
Release Date: 5/19/2022

Changed
Update default endpoint from https://developer[-env].api.autodesk.com to https://cdn[-env].derivative.autodesk.com

I don't know if the error is produced because of this change or what is producing it.

Could someone help me?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**

```
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
    api: 'streamingV2',
    getAccessToken: getForgeToken,
};

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
    var htmlViewer = document.getElementById(ventana.items.keys[0]);
    var viewerConfig;
    viewerConfig = {
        extensions: [
                'Autodesk.DefaultTools.NavTools',
                'Autodesk.Viewing.ZoomWindow',
                'ExtensionToolbarHerramientas',
                'ExtensionImprimir',
                'ExtensionCommand'
        ]
    };
    
    var childNodes = document.getElementById(ventana.items.keys[0]);
    childNodes.innerHTML = "";
    
    viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlViewer, viewerConfig);
    var strtedCode = viewerApp.start();
    if (strtedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');
    
    var documentId = 'urn:' + visorForge.urn;
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onForgeDocumentLoadSuccess, onForgeDocumentLoadFailure);
});
```

Comment: that url does indeed 404 -- from your browser tools you should be able to see what is including that page.

Comment: Could you share more details on how you initialize the Forge Viewer, especially the language setup? As I know, we don't support any language called `es-419`. For Spanish, the supported language symbol is `es`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I've edited the post with the initialization of the viewer.

Comment: Hi, I still have the same problem. I couldn't solve it

Comment: Hi Clara, it seems you are using V6 of the viewer and updating to V7 requieres some migration. Also I'm not familiar with the URL you are providing that has the es-149 on it. Send us an email to forge.help@autodesk.com I will pick up from there and we can also do a call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you already resolved this but I ran into this problem recently. After including *language: 'en'* (or 'es' in your case) in the [InitOptions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/globals/TypeDefs/InitOptions/) this error went away.

```
var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
    api: 'streamingV2',
    getAccessToken: getForgeToken,
    language: 'en'
};
```